# Dump backtrace for a given PID

Tags: php

Suppose a PHP process is hung and I would like to dump the backtrace from shell. Is it possible to dump backtrace of a PHP process given PID? If yes, how do I do it? Similar to `kill -3` in Java.

Comment: If there was a way to sniff the backtrace from shell/another program, don't you think that's a security risk?

Answer (score 0):

[`proc_terminate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-terminate.php)